# Find infimum, supremum and decide wether inf/sup is minimal/maximal.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am asked to find the infimum and supremum of
$X = \{ \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^m - \frac{4}{n} \,|\, m,n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.
($\mathbb{N}$ does not contain $0$)

I found $\inf X = -\frac{9}{2}$ and $\sup X = \frac{1}{4}$. Is this correct? Am right in saying that $\inf X$ is also the minimum of $X$ and $\sup X$ is the maximum of $X$?

Edit: Yes, $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think I get the point that the supremum cannot be the maximum because $\frac{4}{n}$ will always be $> 0$. Thus $\sup X$ is not contained in $X$. Right? What about $\sup X = \frac{1}{4}$, is this wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, apparently I don't know how to calculate. The supremum is $\frac {1}{4}$ and you will not get it, because you are always taking away some small number $\frac {4}{n}$.
I'm rewriting my previous comment.

Comment: You are correct about the infimum and the supremum. You are also correct about the fact that the infimum is minimum, but wrong about the supremum.  Are there some $m,n$ such that the number you get will be $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: @ShakedBader Thank you! How can I accept your answer now? :)

Comment: It's a comment so as far as my knowledge goes you can't accept it, but it's ok, I don't feel like I deserve points for this answer.